# Adding an item into an array

Tags: php, arrays

When the interpreter reaches $pDB->AddLine(5,"Test") it stops responding!
It returns the following error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ... on line 21" Am I missing something? Should I use array_push() instead?

```
<?php
    class pDb{
        protected $m_pArray;
        public function __construct($arr){
            $this->m_pArray = $arr;
        }
        public function RemoveLine($index){ // Todo
        }
        public function ReplaceLine($index,$input){
            if(!$this->m_pArray)return -1;
            $temp = array();
            for($i=0;$i<count($this->m_pArray);$i++){
                ($i == $index) ? $temp[$i] = $input : $temp[$i] = $this->m_pArray[$i]; 
            }
            $this->m_pArray = $temp;
        }
        public function AddLine($index,$input){
            if(!$this->m_pArray)return -1;
            $temp = array();
            for($i=0;$i<count($this->m_pArray);$i++){
                if($i == $index) { $temp[$i] = $input;$i = $i-1; }else{ $temp[$i] = $this->m_pArray[$i]; }
            }
            $this->m_pArray = $temp;
        }
        public function Get(){ if($this->m_pArray)return $this->m_pArray; return null;}
        public function GetLine($i){ if($this->m_pArray)return $this->m_pArray[$i]; return null;}
    }

    $file = file("db.ini");
    for($i=0;$i<count($file);$i++){
        echo $i.": | ".$file[$i]."<br/>";
    }

    echo "<br/>===================================================================================================================<br/><br/>";

    $pDB = new Pdb($file);
    #$pDB->ReplaceLine(5,"Test"); // Works!!!
    $pDB->AddLine(5,"Test"); // Crash!!!
    for($i=0;$i<count($pDB->Get());$i++){
        echo $i.": | ".$pDB->GetLine($i)."<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Fix :
Change

```
for($i=0;$i<count($this->m_pArray);$i++){
                if($i == $index) { $temp[$i] = $input;$i = $i-1; }else{ $temp[$i] = $this->m_pArray[$i]; }
            }
```

to

```
        $done=0;
        for($i=0;$i<count($this->m_pArray)+1;$i++){
            if($i == $index && $done!=1){ $temp[$index] = $input; $done=1;}elseif($done == 1){ $temp[$i] = $this->m_pArray[$i-1]; }else{ $temp[$i] = $this->m_pArray[$i]; }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider your code...

```
for($i=0;$i<count($this->m_pArray);$i++) {
  if($i == $index) {
    $temp[$i] = $input;
    $i = $i-1;
  } else {
    $temp[$i] = $this->m_pArray[$i];
  }
}
```

If `$i == $index`, then you promptly subtract one from `$i`, and go around the loop again. This adds one to `$i`, making it equal to `$index` again, and you fall into the same case - forever! You either need to tie your loop condition to something you change in the `if` branch (i.e. `$temp`), or change the logic here completely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the last statement in this line in the for-loop of "AddLine" is the problem:

```
if($i == $index) { $temp[$i] = $input;$i = $i-1; }
```

As soon as $i reaches 5 (the $index from the function call), you always decrease $i, only to have it increased again by the loop, therefore never proceeding any further. Infinite loop -> timeout.